# What is the minimum force needed to overcome Inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, inertia

This question arose from this statement:

> On Mars, weights would be different but the amount of force needed to overcome inertia would be the same.

The above statement was from [Feynman lectures Vol.1](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_09.html) .

This statement made me to think that **what is the minimum force needed to just overcome Inertia of a body at rest such that it just remains at rest due to its inertia?**

Does it even exist? Because in the equation $F = ma$, we put any value of $F$ and get desired value of $a$ but I have never heard of any non-zero  force producing no net acceleration.

Comment: The quote is just Feynman's poetic way of saying that the [inertial mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_mass) is the same on Mars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no minimal force to overcome inertia.

As you said, because $F=ma$ whatever total force $|F|>0$ will cause an acceleration $|a|>0$, even the smallest force will accelerate the object. How big, given a force $F$, is the acceleration going to be, that depends on the *inertial* mass $m$. So

On Mars, because $m$ is a constant, the same force will lead to the same acceleration - this is what Feynmann is saying: despite the gravitational attraction of Mars being different - i.e. despite the object having a different *weight* it has the same *inertial mass*.

**However** there are cases in which you need a minimum force to move an object, and that is when *static friction* is present. In the presence of friction with friction coefficient $\mu_S$, usually, you need a minimum extra force $$F_S=\mu_s m g$$ to move your object. This is because friction is "counter-pushing" your object if $F<F_S$ so you need to exceed that to overcome friction and push your object.
The equation $F=ma$ is still valid, *but* now $F$ includes a negative term due to friction which you need to overcome, so that $F=F_{yours}-F_{friction}$ and the maximum value that $F_{friction}$ can take is $\mu_S mg $.

Because (this kind of) friction depends on the *weight* $mg$ of your object, on Mars this force $F_S$ might be different because the acceleration of gravity $g$ on Mars is different. But this is *not* what Feynmann was telling you in that paragraph, it's extra ;)